# Split file with Space where column data is also having space

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi  I have data file which is having space as delimiter and also the data each column also contain spaces..How can i split it using spark program using scala:
Sample data Filed:
student.txt

3 columns:
Name
Address
Id

```
Name         Address               Id
Abhi Rishii  Bangalore,Karnataka  1234
Rinki siyty  Hydrabad,Andra      2345
```

Output Data frame should be:

```
 |Name         |City   |State     |Id--|
  +-------------+------+-----------+-----+
  | Abhi Rishii|Bangalore|Karnataka|1234|
  | Rinki siyty|Hydrabad |Andra    |2345|
  +----+-----+-----------+---------+-----+
```

Comment: Can the data be inside quotes? Then you can read it. What is the source of your input file?

Comment: The data is not divided by space but by tabs (\t).

Answer (score 0):

Your file is a tab delimited file.
You can use Spark's csv reader to read this file directly into a dataframe.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
var studentDf = spark.read.format("csv")     // Use "csv" for both TSV and CSV
                .option("header", "true")  
                .option("delimiter", "\t") // Set delimiter to tab .
                .load("student.txt")
                .withColumn("_tmp", split($"Address", "\\,"))
                .withColumn($"_tmp".getItem(0).as("City"))
                .withColumn($"_tmp".getItem(1).as("State"))
                .drop("_tmp")
                .drop("Address")


studentDf .show()

  |Name         |City   |State     |Id--|
  +-------------+------+-----------+-----+
  | Abhi Rishii|Bangalore|Karnataka|1234|
  | Rinki siyty|Hydrabad |Andra    |2345|
  +----+-----+-----------+---------+-----+
```

Comment: But :Address column is having 2 fields in the incoming input file  with CityName,State.So How will i split this address column so that in the resulting data frame i can have city and State as 2 separate column

Comment: Thank u soo much:-)U saved my day:-)@remis haroon